# Language query(Python?)

Tags: python

I Know this is stupid but can you make JS games on the pi or does it have to be in python.
I find HTML/JS/JQ easier and better to work with so I just wondered.

Comment: Yes you can make JS games. But as the name says JS is a scripting language, and the code can grow really big and out of control, and Python is programming language and with the correct methodologies you can create good code. I am not sure about how you would write a web game with python because I don't use python. You might have more luck with HTML5 Canvas and jQuery. Look for HTML Canvas games or something

Comment: @ppumkin 1) Scripting languages *are* [programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), and python is also considered a scripting language. 2) You can grow code "big and out of control" w/ python just as easily as you can w/ js. 3) Modern browsers use a js engine with a 2-step compiler (code->bytecode), making the two languages contextually identical. 4) JQuery is a library written in javascript for use in javascript applications (it is actually referenced in the question as "JQ").

Comment: Python is a powerful programming language because  you can do Object Oriented programming with, Modularized programs or simple scripts. A script generally is something that the user can edit, like VBScript based on VB.NET but does evertyhgin through DLL calls instead of compiling into  abinary. Unfortunately there is no solid distinction by this and the main difference is how they are used. All I meant that OO does not exist in JS, its prototyped and loosely coupled. But it is very popular because its lightweight and fast, and ie .NET cannot render graphics in Web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a a point, Javascript **is a programming language**. As is Python, C, Java, and even [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).  As others have mentioned, Python and Javascript are also considered *scripting languages* which is a higher level than their C and Java counterparts. In short, those languages are easier to learn and use, but won't be nearly as efficient as coding in a lower level language.

It is entirely possible to write games in Javascript, though it will probably also require HTML5, and a web browser. Mozilla has an interesting list of *[Javascript game engines and tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tools/Engines_and_tools)*, and it's worth noting that the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor is written in a combination of CoffeeScript and Javascript (plus a webkit browser).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As @ppumkin points out though, javascript is a scripting laguage for the browser, and as such, garbage collection and memory usage will not be as efficient as programming in a language such as python. c++, et al.
It can be more difficult to trace memory leaks in javascript.